# RXJava - buffer observable 1 until observable 2 emits one item

Tags: android, rx-java

I want following behaviour:

`observableMain` should buffers all items until `observableResumed` emits a value. Then `observableMain` should emit all buffered and all feature values...

What I do in my `activity's` `onCreate`:

```
 PublishSubject<T> subject = ...; // I create a subject to emit items to and to subscribe to

 // 1) I create a main observable from my subject
 final Observable<T> observableMain = subject
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

 // 2) I use a custom base class in which I can register listeners 
 // for the onResume event and which I can query the isResumed state! 
 // I call the object the pauseResumeProvider!

 // 2.1) I create an observable, it emits a value ONLY if my activity is resumed
 final Observable<Boolean> obsIsResumed = Observable
            .defer(() -> Observable.just(pauseResumeProvider.isActivityResumed()))
            .skipWhile(aBoolean -> aBoolean != true);

 // 2.2) I create a second observable, it emits a value as soon as my activity is resumed
 final Observable<Boolean> obsOnResumed = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber)
        {
            pauseResumeProvider.addPauseResumeListener(new IPauseResumeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResume() {
                    pauseResumeProvider.removePauseResumeListener(this);
                    subscriber.onNext(true);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPause() {

                }
            });
        }
    });

// 2.3) I combine the resumed observables and only emit the FIRST value I can get
final Observable<Boolean> observableResumed = Observable
        .concat(obsIsResumed, obsOnResumed)
        .first();

// 3) here I'm stuck
// 3 - Variant 1:
Observable<T> observable = observableMain
            .buffer(observableResumed)
            .concatMap(values -> Observable.from(values));
// 3 - Variant 2:
// Observable<T> observable = observableMain.delay(t -> observableResumed);

// 4) I emit events to my my subject...
// this event is LOST!
subject.onNext("Test in onCreate");
```

**Problem**

All items that are send to the `subject` after the `activity` is resumed are working, all items before are lost (at least with the `delay` solution). I can't get my desired behaviour to work. How would I correctly solve that?

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated. Why is there a requirement that values only get emitted when your activity is resumed?

Comment: I want to reuse one observable in my activity and I want to update the UI from background tasks, so I want to control when items are emitted (I don't want the UI to be updated, if the activity is not resumed and I don't want to lose update events either). I want to replace an existing eventbus + queue system I'm using for quite some time with an RXJava solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a source replayed and use delaySubscription to trigger the real subscription.

```
PublishSubject<Integer> emitNow = PublishSubject.create();

ConnectableObservable<T> co = source.replay();

co.subscribe();

co.connect();

co.delaySubscription(emitNow).subscribe(...);

emitNow.onNext(1);
```

**Edit:**

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/1c54e5a4f64f9b1e46bdcf62b4222f08) with an operator you can `lift` into a sequence that can pause and resume emissions from upstream.

Comment: This looks very promising. Will test it a little more. Remembering the `ConnectableObservable` and unsubscribe from it and resubscribe to it should make it possible to pause/resume my main subscription and never lose an emitted item (which is what I want in the end)

Comment: You can't pause with this setup. It will run in the background and once you signal emitNow, you get all the data.

Comment: I think, unsubscribing from `co` and resubscribing to it in the same way would work like pausing?

Comment: I see, that's not working. Any ideas how to achieve that? I want to be able to resubscribe to an observable and only get the items reemited, that have not been emited already. I want to pause my subscription when the activity is paused and resume it when the activity is resumed and get all items that were emited in the meantime

Comment: Disconnecting drops the co.delaySubscription.subscribe chain entirely, plus you'd get the whole sequence from the beginning. `distinct()` might help depending on your data type

Comment: You'd need a custom operator for that.

Comment: Thanks. This was helping a lot

Comment: I tried creating my simple library (event bus with queuing function), but I can't get it working... The complete project can be found on github, I created an issue (https://github.com/MFlisar/RXBus/issues/1) with some infos. Maybe you can help with that? I appreciate your help anyway. Thanks

Comment: I created a new question for my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36965828/rxjava-pausing-with-internal-queuing-and-resuming-emission-based-on-another

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to actually emit the value. Updated the gist.

Comment: This seems to work fine now. Still, I have one small problem: when sending an event to the bus, it can happen, that the valve evaluates, that it should emit items, but when the items actually is emited, this is not true anymore (the activity may have been paused in the meantime). Anyway to get this solved? I have only one solution: when receiving an event i check the state and just resend it to the bus...

Comment: The valveOpen should be evaluated before emission. There could be a small window between the check and the emission, but it's the nature of concurrent systems. Do you have some unit test that shows the issue?

Comment: I've still problems and I've setup a structure that will fail every now and then here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685467/rxjava-make-a-pausable-observable-with-buffer-and-window-for-example I've tried to make an alternative more simple solution (this seems to work) but I still don't know if it is better for my use case or not nor if it solves the problem (as I'm not sure what the problem is). Maybe you can say something to the other question?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to delay emissions of source (hot) observable until "valve" opens

```
source.delay(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<Boolean> call(Integer integer) {
        return valve.filter(new Func1<Boolean, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Boolean isOpen) {
                //emits only when isOpen is true 
                return isOpen;
            }
        });
    }
})
.subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Integer integer) {
        System.out.println("out: " + integer);
    }
});
```

Gist: [Rx Valve](https://gist.github.com/neven-s/f865bd3c1fb0212862f4c079511eb6a1)