# RXJava - make a pausable observable (with buffer and window for example)

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I want to create observables that do following:

- buffer all items, while they are paused
- immediately emit items, while they are not paused
- the pause/resume trigger must come from another observable
- it must be save to be used by observables that do not run on the main thread and it must be save change the paused/resumed state from the main thread

I want to use a `BehaviorSubject<Boolean>` as trigger and bind this trigger to an activity's `onResume` and `onPause` event. (Code example appended)

**Question**

I've setup something, but it is not working as intended. I use it like following:

```
Observable o = ...;
// Variant 1
o = o.lift(new RxValve(getPauser(), 1000, getPauser().getValue())
// Variant 2
// o = o.compose(RXPauser.applyPauser(getPauser()));
o
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();
```

Currently the problem is, that Variant 1 should work fine, but sometimes, the events are just not emitted - the valve is not emitting, until the valve everything is working (may be a threading problem...)! Solution 2 is much simplier and seems to work, but I'm not sure if it is really better, I don't think so. I'm actually not sure, why solution one is failing sometimes so I'm not sure if solution 2 solves the (currently for me unknown) problem...

Can someone tell me what could be the problem or if the simple solution should work reliably? Or show me a reliable solution?

**Code**

*RxValue*

https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/1c54e5a4f64f9b1e46bdcf62b4222f08

*RXPauser functions*

```
public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applyPauser(Observable<Boolean> pauser)
{
    return observable -> pauser(observable, pauser);
}

private static <T> Observable<T> pauser(Observable<T> source, Observable<Boolean> pauser)
{
    // this observable buffers all items that are emitted while emission is paused
    Observable<T> sharedSource = source.publish().refCount();
    Observable<T> queue = sharedSource
            .buffer(pauser.distinctUntilChanged().filter(isResumed -> !isResumed), aBoolean -> pauser.distinctUntilChanged().filter(isResumed -> isResumed))
            .flatMap(l -> Observable.from(l))
            .doOnNext(t -> L.d(RXPauser.class, "Pauser QUEUED: " + t));

    // this observable emits all items that are emitted while emission is not paused
    Observable<T> window = sharedSource.window(pauser.distinctUntilChanged().filter(isResumed -> isResumed), aBoolean ->  pauser.distinctUntilChanged().filter(isResumed -> !isResumed))
            .switchMap(tObservable -> tObservable)
            .doOnNext(t -> L.d(RXPauser.class, "Pauser NOT QUEUED: " + t));

    // combine both observables
    return queue.mergeWith(window)
            .doOnNext(t -> L.d(RXPauser.class, "Pauser DELIVERED: " + t));
}
```

*Activity*

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final BehaviorSubject<Boolean> pauser = BehaviorSubject.create(false);

    public BaseActivity(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super(args);
        final Class<?> clazz = this.getClass();
        pauser
                .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> {
                    L.d(clazz, "Pauser unsubscribed!");
                })
                .subscribe(aBoolean -> {
                    L.d(clazz, "Pauser - " + (aBoolean ? "RESUMED" : "PAUSED"));
                });
    }

    public PublishSubject<Boolean> getPauser()
    {
        return pauser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        pauser.onNext(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        pauser.onNext(false);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: People trying to answer this question are, so far, missing one crucial requirement that is made very clear in the question:
_"the pause/resume trigger must come from another observable"_.
They are not wanting a fixed time schedule.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use `.buffer()` operator passing it observable, defining when to stop buffering, sample from book:

```
Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).take(10)
    .buffer(Observable.interval(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

from chapter 5, 'Taming the sequence': https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%203%20-%20Taming%20the%20sequence/5.%20Time-shifted%20sequences.md

You can use `PublishSubject` as `Observable` to feed it elements in your custom operator. Every time you need to start buffering, create instance by `Observable.defer(() -> createBufferingValve())`

Answer (score 2):

I made similar thing for logging events.
Subject collects some events, and one time in 10 seconds pushes them to server.

The main idea is, for example you have class `Event`.

```
public class Event {

    public String jsonData;

    public String getJsonData() {
        return jsonData;
    }

    public Event setJsonData(String jsonData) {
        this.jsonData = jsonData;
        return this;
    }
}
```

You should create queue for events:

```
private PublishSubject<Event> eventQueue = PublishSubject.create();
```

It can be `BehaviorSubject`, it doesn't matter

Then you should create the logic, which will handle pushing events to the server:

```
    eventObservable = eventQueue.asObservable()
            .buffer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)   //flush events every 10 seconds
            .toList()
            .doOnNext(new Action1<List<Event>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<Event> events) {
                    apiClient.pushEvents(events);     //push your event
                }
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<List<Event>>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<List<Event>> call(Throwable throwable) {
                    return null;    //make sure, that on error will be never called
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Then you should subscribe to it, and retain subscription, until you don't need it:

```
eventSubscription = eventObservable.subscribe()
```

Home this helps